# APC change to smart slot / card interface

Tags: ups, smart, apc

I bought a new APC SMT1000C 1000VA UPS, which has the smart card interface on the back.  I was planning to reuse my old AP9606 network card, but I discovered that APC has modified the slot to block the old cards.  See photos below, new card has 2 vertical cutouts, while old card has no cutouts.

The size of the card and connector look identical, but the new UPS' have 2 meta bars which prevent old cards from fitting into the new slots.

Does anyone know if the old cards (eg: AP9606) will work?  Was this a sales exercise to force people to buy new smart cards?  Or are they really electrically incompatible?  I'm prepare to do a little metal work on the old card if someone can confirm they work.

[image: New Card] [image: Old Card]

Comment: What's is your new model number?